# JSON to JSON transformation libraries

Tags: json, transformation

What are some of the best & most efficient JSON to JSON transformation libraries ?
I only know about [Jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt.git). Does anybody know about other open source libraries exist on similar lines ?

Comment: There won't be a best library without concrete requirements. If you tell us how exactly you need to transform JSON, this question would be a much better fit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of libraries for JSON parsing, but there are not many that are for JSON to JSON transformations.  https://github.com/joelvh/json2json is one.  Are to discern a library without knowing what language you want to code in.

If you are looking for something where you don't need to code, try [Data Mutanda](http://datamutanda.com).